# Alfresco FTS wildcards

Tags: wildcard, alfresco, full-text-search

I have a model in alfresco with following type:

```
<type name="namedobject">
  <title>NamedObject</title>
  <parent>object</parent>
  <properties>
    <property name="objectName">
      <type>d:text</type>
      <index enabled="true">
        <atomic>true</atomic>
        <stored>false</stored>
        <tokenised>both</tokenised>
      </index>
    </property>
  </properties>
</type>
```

A have an object of this type with `objectName` = `James Warlick`. I want to find it using alfresco FTS and wildcards. I tried following queries in node browser:

```
objectName: james     => OK
objectName: *james*   => not found (?)
objectName: *jame*    => OK
objectName: *ames     => not found (?)
objectName: *ame      => OK
```

I suppose all 5 queries must return this object but 2 and 4 don't work. I don't understand the reason.
I've read [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Full_Text_Search_Query_Syntax#Wildcards) article, but it didn't help.
I use Alfresco Community - v3.4.0

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Tried with quotes: "james". Results:

```
objectName: "james"      => OK
objectName: "*james*"    => OK
objectName: "*jame*"     => not found (?)
objectName: "*ames"      => not found (?)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get more informations on that matter ?

Comment: @Vincent, unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting quotes around the keyword? --> "*james*" and "*ames"?